# How can i execute a code only after the promise is done

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise, axios

every thing work in my code, the problem is that `this.loading=false` run before the `for()` is done sending all the requests.

How can make `this.loading=false` get executed only after the `for()` finishes sending all the requests ?
i hope you got the idea.

```
methods:{
    fileChange(event){
        this.loading=true
        //code
        for(var i=0; i < tasks.length; i++){
            //code
            axios.post('/api/operation', data)
                .then(response=>{
                    this.operations.push(name:response.data.name});
                })
                
        }
        
        //i want to the bellow code to be executed after for() is finnished!
        this.loading=false
    },

},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use async/await

```
methods: {
    async fileChange(event) {
      this.loading = true
      for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
        const {data} = await axios.post('/api/operation', data) // << whats data?
        
        this.operations.push({ name: data.name })
      }
      this.loading = false
    },
},
```

Comment: As other answer says ....using `await` in a for loop is simply bad advice

Comment: @MichalLevý yup, depends on the urls, if there is 300 tasks all hitting the same endpoint its better to do them sequentially rather than all at once else it will hammer the server and users internet and connections with 300 requests all at once, also if OP wanted to stop it they could also simply toggle a variable, additionally the OP could use a websocket instead of posting to an endpoint which would be better all-round.. so not simply bad advice just one way to do it

Answer (score 2):

Your code does set `this.loading` to `false` after all requests are *sent*; did you mean you want it to be set after all responses from all requests have returned? I hope I understood your question correctly.

In that case, you can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled): each of them takes an array of `Promise`s (for example, `axios` requests), and returns another `Promise` which resolves with the results once all the promises in the array finish.

In simpler words, it allows you to combine many promises into one, which completes only once they all completed.

For example:

```js
methods: {
  fileChange(event) {
    this.loading = true;

    // Send requests and store the Promises in an array.
    // Each promise resolves to the response's `response.data.name` field.
    const requestPromises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
      const promise = axios.post('/api/operation', data)
        .then(response => response.data.name);
      requestPromises.push(promise);
    }

    // Executed once all requests return a response
    Promise.all(requestPromises)
      .then(names => {
        // Push all operation names into operations
        this.operations.push(...names);
        this.loadaing = false;
      });
  }
},
```

(Note: you can make the code much more elegant using `Array.map()` and `async`/`await`)

The difference between `Promise.all()` and `Promise.allSettled()` is regarding the handling of errors - `Promise.all()` fails (rejects) if *any* of the promises passed into it fail, while `Promise.allSettled()` always resolves to an array of objects, each containing data about whether the operation succeeded and its associated values.

Edit: using `await` inside the `for` loop will work, **but it's highly inefficient**, as your code will wait for one request to end before sending the next; if you have 50 requests to send, and each takes approximately 100ms to return, **using `await` inside `for` will take 50 * 100 = 5000 ms, or 5 seconds to end**; using `Promise.all`/`Promise.allSettled` will keep that number close to 100ms, as all requests are sent together.